# Symfony fetchAll by filter

Tags: symfony

I would like to filter the output from user records. I will filter users like is active, inactive or have specified role or user which is assigned to an district.

I create a function in my user repository.

```
public function getListBy($filter)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
    $associateMapping = $this->getClassMetadata()->getAssociationMappings();

    foreach ($filter as $field => $value) {
         if (array_key_exists($field, $associateMapping)) {
            switch ($field) {
                case 'roles':
                    $qb->innerJoin('i.'.$field, 'r');
                    $qb->andWhere('r.id=:id')->setParameter('id', $value->getId());
                break;
                case 'wards':
                    $qb->innerJoin('i.'.$field, 'd');
                    $qb->andWhere('d.id=:id')->setParameter('id', $value->getId());
                break;
         }
    }

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

It's work if i filter onyl for a specified district or only for a specified role. The function returns the affected users.

But if i combine the filters and filter a user in a specified district with a specified role i get no results.

Simple example of my table structure:

User:

```
+----+----------+
| id | username |
+----+----------+
|  1 | testuser |
+----+----------+
```

Role:

```
+----+----------+
| id | rolename |
+----+----------+
|  1 | admin    |
+----+----------+
```

District:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | ny   |
+----+------+
```

Relation tables:

Roles to user:

```
+---------+---------+
| role_id | user_id |
+---------+---------+
|       1 |       1 |
+---------+---------+
```

District to user

```
+-------------+---------+
| district_id | user_id |
+-------------+---------+
|           1 |       1 |
+-------------+---------+
```

Does anyone have a suggestion what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

The sql response i receive look like this.

SELECT u0_.id AS id0, u0_.firstName AS firstName1, u0_.lastName AS lastName2, u0_.username AS username3, u0_.password AS password4, u0_.is_active AS is_active5, u0_.createDate AS createDate6, u0_.gender AS gender7, u0_.title AS title8, u0_.modifiedDate AS modifiedDate9, u0_.lastLogin AS lastLogin10, u0_.maritalStatus AS maritalStatus11, u0_.children AS children12, u0_.birthDate AS birthDate13, u0_.placeOfBirth AS placeOfBirth14, u0_.nationality AS nationality15, u0_.newUser AS newUser16 FROM user u0_ INNER JOIN user_role u2_ ON u0_.id = u2_.user_id INNER JOIN role r1_ ON r1_.id = u2_.role_id INNER JOIN user_district u4_ ON u0_.id = u4_.user_id INNER JOIN district d3_ ON d3_.id = u4_.district_id WHERE r1_.id = ? AND d3_.id = ?;

And if i execute this query on my database it's return one result. But in the app i do not get an result

```
$qb->getQuery()->getResult()
```

**Update 2**

I am despair. Now i remove anything in my repository function and write only this lines.

```
public function getListBy($criteria)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');

    $qb->innerJoin('i.roles', 'roles');
    $qb->andWhere('roles.id=:id')->setParameter('id', 9);

    $qb->innerJoin('i.wards', 'wards');
    $qb->andWhere('wards.id=:id')->setParameter('id', 1);

    // If i execute this output in my database, i get one row as result
    echo $qb->getQuery()->getSql();

    // But if i count the result, it return 0
    var_dump(count($qb->getQuery()->getResult()));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 }
```

Unfortunately I have no more idea is very strange. Had anyone ever had this problem.

**Update 3, i solve my problem:**

My mistake was in the function "setParameter". I use in both cases in the switch statement the same identifier for replacing the parameter. After i do not use the set parameter, everything is ok.

```
public function getListBy($criteria)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');

    $qb->innerJoin('i.roles', 'roles');
    $qb->andWhere('roles.id=9');

    $qb->innerJoin('i.wards', 'wards');
    $qb->andWhere('wards.id=1');

    // If i execute this output in my database, i get one row as result
    echo $qb->getQuery()->getSql();

    // But if i count the result, it return 0
    var_dump(count($qb->getQuery()->getResult()));

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
 }
```

But i do not understand why is the same name for an identifier an problem. Mybe anyone can explain me this situation?

Comment: try echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL(); to output the create sql query and run it on the db to see if the query was create right

Comment: I try this , but i do not see the complete sql statement. After 757 characters the output displays only "...length=757"

Comment: try echo $qb->getQuery()->getSQL();die; so the execution terminates after the echo

Comment: With echo now i see the complete query. Before i try var_dump, sorry my mistake

Comment: does the query look like you expected it?

Comment: Yes, the query look good and i get over the database the correct row, if i execute the output from "getSql". But i do not understand , why the "getResult" return me 0. Unfortunately i have no more ideas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62540/discussion-between-mab82x-and-andre).